# How to include Laravel Controller file like blade

Tags: laravel, laravel-4

First my master.blade file include menu bar using this

Include Blade file menu.blade.php

```
 @include('menu')
```

But Finally I realize to send some data from db to menubar, then I create controller, Controller name is MenuController, then I create route "**admin-menu**". **Now I want to include that link to my master blade.** how to do that thank you,

Comment: So is your question "how can I conditionally include partials in a view?" (i.e. in some routes you want to include `menu` and some `admin-menu`)

Comment: @alexrussell no, using MenuController pass data to menu.blade.php, how to include that menu.blade.php with controller passed data

Comment: Added an answer, hopefully that covers all your use-cases for passing data into views.

Answer (score 1):

To pass data to a view from either a route closure or a controller you do one of the following:

```
$now = \Carbon\Carbon::now();

View::make('my-view', ['name' => 'Alex', 'date' => $now]);       // pass data into View:::make()
View::make('my-view')->with(['name' => 'Alex', 'date' => $now]); // pass data into View#with()
View::make('my-view')->withName('Alex')->withDate($now);         // use fluent View#with()
```

So you'd just use them in the View::make() call as you presumably already are:

```
// in a route closure
Route::get('some-route', function () {
    return View::make('menu', ['name' => 'Alex']);
});

// in a controller
public function someRoute()
{
    return View::make('menu', ['name' => 'Alex']);
}
```

Interestingly, in a lot of frameworks/templating systems, if you wanted to include a partial, you'd pass the data you want to be available in that partial in the partial call, but Laravel doesn't quite do this. For example in a made-up system you may have something like this:

```
// in controller:
$this->render('home', ['name' => 'Alex', 'age' => 30]);

// home.php
<?php echo $name; ?>
<?php echo $this->partial('home-age', ['age' => $age]); ?>

// home-age.php
<?php echo $age; ?>
```

But in Laravel, all current view variables are automatically included into partials for you. Now I tend to like to specify the variables anyway (Blade does allow you to do this as above), and obviously it can be used to override a view variable:

```
// route:
return View::make('home', ['name' => 'Alex', 'age' => 30, 'gender' => 'male']);

// home.blade.php
{{ $name }}
@include('home-extra', ['age' => 20])

// home-extra.blade.php
{{ $age }}
{{ $gender }}
```

The above code would output:

```
Alex
20
male
```

So the age is overridden in the `@include`, but the un-overridden `gender` is just passed along. Hopefully that makes sense.